# String cant write to CSV file Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv

I don't necessarily understand why this bit of code is incorrect. I understand the error in that string class doesn't have a method map. But I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this error.

The error

```
`<<': undefined method `map' for #<String:0x000001020b8940> (NoMethodError)
```

The but of code

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("dent-file.html"))

new_array = doc.search("p").map do |para|
     para.text
end

CSV.open("dent.csv", "w") do |csv|
   new_array.each do |string|
     csv << string
   end
end
```

I want to write each element of the `newdoc` array to each line of the csv file dent.csv.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`CSV#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-3C-3C) accepts an array or a [`CSV::Row`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html). Convert the string to an array.

```
csv << [string]
```